# my pyhon code if [P2, P3, P4, P5] is [not None, None, None, None] it should work but isnt

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, list-comprehension, func, nonetype

why it doesn't work? it should work here

```
def say_hi(P1, P2 = None, P3 = None, P4 = None, P5 = None):
    if [P2, P3, P4, P5] is [not None, None, None, None]:
        print(f'hi {P1}')
        print(f'hi {P2}')

say_hi('Jack', 'Rose')
```

why my code doesn't work?
it execute nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is meaning that these two object's is the same object. Not the equal.
You need "==".
https://dbader.org/blog/difference-between-is-and-equals-in-python

Try this.

```
def say_hi(*P):                                                             
     for p in P:
         print(f'hi {p}')

say_hi('Jack', 'Rose')
```

You can call function with number of parameters you need. All this parameters will be element of array "P".

You can read [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp#:%7E:text=The%20terms%20parameter%20and%20argument,function%20when%20it%20is%20called.) about python function and parameters.

Comment: I used to do that but it return(print) nothing

Comment: @God_ppt, do you want to call this functions with a different parameters number and the function should print every not None element?

Comment: yep I want that

Comment: @God_ppt please, mark answer as accepted or give some callback

Comment: @Victor thanks you 
I don't know to to give feedback or anything else cuz I can't find a comment section

Comment: I see it all I want to thank you
I want to ask you that how to mark answer as accepted?

Comment: @God_ppt check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) please xD Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check your location of "not".
Here is the answer.

```
def say_hi(P1, P2 = None, P3 = None, P4 = None, P5 = None):
    if [P2, P3, P4, P5] is not [None, None, None, None]:
        print(f'hi {P1}')
        print(f'hi {P2}')

say_hi('Jack', 'Rose')
```

Comment: oh thanks but I want to ask you more
`def say_hi(P1, P2 = None, P3 = None, P4 = None, P5 = None):
    if [P2, P3, P4, P5] is not [None, None, None, None]:
        print(f'hi {P1}')
        print(f'hi {P2}')
        print(f'hi {P3}')
        print(f'hi {P4}')
        print(f'hi {P5}')
say_hi('Jack', 'Rose')`

it return 

hi Jack
hi Rose
hi None
hi None
hi None
how make sure that hi None is not execute without add more parameter?